# Exporting a Variable from bash script does not work, does work if I change the variable to any other name

Tags: linux, bash

This is the strangest behaviour I have ever seen. I know you might be shocked to see the below explanation but yes this is happening.

I'm trying to export a variable name which is `LON_GEMINI_BOX` from a bash script.

And trying to access the value of this variable in a makefile to define some specific things.

which looks like:
In bash script,

```
export LON_GEMINI_BOX = 1
```

In makefile,

```
ifeq ($(LON_GEMINI_BOX), 1)
This is how im defined
EXTRA_CFLAGS += 
EXTRA_CFLAGS += 
else
why is this happening
endif
```

I always end up in else part while building.
If I just tweak variable name to `LON_GEMINI1_BOX` or anything else other than `LON_GEMINI_BOX` it is exported and works as expected.

I'm struggling to identity what is the problem.

Comment: `LON_GEMINI_BOX = 1` does not work in `bash`; you need `LON_GEMINI_BOX=1`

Comment: Sorry! about the typo. but still doesn't work with LON_GEMINI_BOX=1

Comment: You should edit your question and correct typos...

Comment: Edit your question to put your **actual, complete code**. Until you do this, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend eliminating all blanks in makefile conditionals.
See this makefile, which works perfectly.

```
TXT="--"
ifeq ($(LON_GEMINI_BOX),1)
 TXT="works!"
 EXTRA_CFLAGS +=
 EXTRA_CFLAGS +=
else
 TXT="why is this happening"
endif
all:
    @echo $(TXT)
```

Comment: The problem is just by changing the name it starts working, with same name it doesn't work. I feel there is something specific to the name. Could there be anywhere the export of such names  blocked.

Comment: I have searched the entire source to see if this variable name is unset any where else. but does not seem so.

Comment: sorry somewhere else the same variable was defined like below and fixed it LON_GEMINI_BOX=y. Thanks for all your responses.